# Nested list comprehension doesn't append element

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have this iteration

```
for item in result:
   for subitem in item.find_all('strong'):
      line = subitem.get_text()
        if line:
          temp.append(line)
```

It works well but I would like to implement it through list comprehension. Here is my attempt

```
[subitem.get_text() for subitem in item.find_all('strong') if subitem.get_text() for item in result]
```

but something doesn't work as it should be.

Answer (score 4):

The `for` clauses in a list comprehension should appear in the same order they would in the analogous nested loop.

```
[subitem.get_text() for item in result for subitem in item.find_all('strong') if subitem.get_text()]
```

Comment: Right..I have realized just now...thank you very much